# Toilet Paper Mounting Bracket

Tags: brackets

My toilet paper roll holder's mounting bracket has broken.

I don't need to buy a whole new unit, just the mounting bracket.  However, I am unable to find it anywhere.  Tried the google on many variations with no results.

Does anyone know what this is called and/or where I can buy it from??
[image]

Comment: Just FYI the mounting bracket will probably cost you $1 less than buying the whole thing again.   Not sure your search time is worth it.

Comment: I would drill and tap for a 1/4-20 flat-head screw. That and epoxy would do well.

Comment: @isherwood, I think the "turret" part has broken off the bracket, not sure from your comment which way (location and direction) you mean to drill?

Comment: Screw from the backside through the plate and into the post.

Comment: Did a hoarder steal your toilet paper?

Answer (score 1):

The [installation instructions](https://www.us.kohler.com/webassets/kpna/catalog/pdf/en/1312043_2.pdf) for a similar fixture call that part a "wall plate". I would bet you would need to contact the manufacturer.

Comment: That's a great start, however my bracket has a round pin.  I'll continue my elusive search.  :)

Comment: Go buy a new one. Can see why this is back again.

Answer (score 0):

With out knowing bracket and why not working . It looks like you could rotate it ,and change the set screw may be worn.

Comment: The post appears to be broken off the plate.